# turn off green light Android 12 in a specific app

Tags: javascript, adb

exist a one adb command to disabled green light off but on a specific application, example: device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false specific_apk

Thanks!!

Green apk light off
device_config put privacy camera_mic_icons_enabled false default

Comment: Why should Google introduce a security feature that reveal malicious apps using microphone and camera if there would be an option to disable this feature for certain apps? I don't see a good reason to disable this feature.  Feel free to try to convince me with your arguments why you need such a feature.

Comment: I am making an application that uses the location and the microphone in bursts, every certain interval, it is not for any evil purpose or anything like that. It doesn't bother me for the other applications, it's also for my own phone. I found a way to deactivate it globally, which I don't want just so I don't get hacked